# Remove border in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, border

I would like to remove the white border in a **.png** output file, using `ggplot2`.
I'm using Windows 10 with Rstudio, `ggplot2`, and `geom_raster`. After spending time searching on forums, and playing with some parameters, I ended up with this codes (that still does not work):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)

png(file = "Out.png")

par(mar=rep(0, 4), plt=c(0.1,0.9,0.1,0.9), xpd=NA)

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
geom_raster(aes(fill = density))+
theme(axis.line        = element_blank(),
      axis.text        = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks       = element_blank(),
      axis.title       = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      panel.border     = element_blank(),
      panel.margin = unit(0,"null"),
      legend.position = "none",
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      plot.background  = element_blank(),
      plot.margin = rep(unit(0,"null"),4))

dev.off()
```

This code gives this png:

[image]

Comment: Some answers here: [how-do-i-remove-margins-surrounding-the-plot-area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254533/when-using-ggplot-in-r-how-do-i-remove-margins-surrounding-the-plot-area/31256788#31256788)

Comment: and here: [ggplot2 theme with no axes or grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313285/ggplot2-theme-with-no-axes-or-grid).

Comment: Thanks for your different links to similar cases. After some tries, it seems that only the one provided by Floo using the cowplot package worked in this case (maybe because of geom_raster or package versions).

Comment: It looks like you were missing the `scale_*_*(expand = c(0, 0))` for both axes and `axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "mm"))`.  This is in [one of the given links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254533/when-using-ggplot-in-r-how-do-i-remove-margins-surrounding-the-plot-area/31256788#31256788), but not quite in the marked duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Even when it is a little bit hacky you can use the `cowplot`-Package to achieve that as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)
require(cowplot)
base <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
  theme_nothing() + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) 
plot_grid(base, scale=1.1)
```

- `theme_nothing() + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)` is a short handle for what you did with `theme(...)`
 - `plot_grid(..., scale=1.1)` is the important part as it resizes the plot to overlap the white border.

This gives you:

[image]

Comment: Hi Floo, yes it works. How do you figure out the 1.1. Just to add an information: it will work if we don't use legend. But that is fine enough! Thanks very much.