# geom_sf how to trim white space without saving plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to trim the white space from a [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) map plot that was created using `geom_sf()`. I have found multiple resources discussing removing white space when saving a plot using `ggsave()`. I am hoping to remove the white space without having to save it, though.

Removing white space using `ggsave()` - [R ggplot, remove white margins in ggsave/ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346111/r-ggplot-remove-white-margins-in-ggsave-ggplot)

Please find below a reproducible example:

```r
library(spData); library(sf); library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
data("us_states", package = "spData")

north_carolina = read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

nc_plot <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = north_carolina)
```

Now, I want `nc_plot` to appear at the very bottom left hand corner of a `ggdraw()` plot. The coordinates of a `ggdraw()` plot start from the bottom left. So, x = 0, y = 0 should be the bottom left.

```
ggdraw() + draw_plot(nc_plot, x = 0, y = 0)
```

As you can see, though, the plot is all the way left but not all the way at the bottom. This is because there is white space above and below the plot. I want to remove the white space from the plot so that I can have the map at the bottom left.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce your last code. Would you mind adding an image of the output of ggdraw?

Comment: @Maël, I added an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete @Skaqqs' answer and offer you an alternative solution, you can also continue to use the `cowplot` package by modifying your last line of code as follows:

- Code

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)


ggdraw() + draw_plot(nc_plot, x = -0.24, y = -0.34, scale = 0.5)
```

- Visualization

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: nicely done. If this is the result OP was shooting for, I'll delete my answer and add my code as a comment here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very nice feedback @Skaqqs. I think your solution is worth mine (I upvoted it) and your post would deserve to stay as an answer as well. That said, it is up to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Can share more about what you're trying to accomplish? You say you want to remove whitespace, but you also want the plot to be at the bottom left of whitespace. What is your ultimate goal here? Let me know if I missed something.

I believe the whitespace is added outside of your ggplot based on your graphic device and ggplot margins. You can control the ggplot margins in `theme()` ([like in this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254533/when-using-ggplot-in-r-how-do-i-remove-margins-surrounding-the-plot-area/31255629)). You could remove the whitespace by defining your graphic device to the same dimensions as your ggplot object.

If you wanted to place the plot at the bottom left of whitespace, you could define your graphic device space and then plot within that area with one of your favorite plot layout tools. For example:

```
g <- ggplotGrob(nc_plot)
ggplot() + theme_void() + xlim(0,10) + ylim(0,10) +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = g,
    xmin = -0.5,
    xmax = 3,
    ymin = -2,
    ymax = 5)
```

[image]

edit: example of the role of plot and plot margins (blue area) and the graphic device. Note that the graphic device fills the plotting window with whitespace depending on how the device is sized. The total plot area is shown in blue.

```
  geom_sf(data = north_carolina) + 
  theme(panel.background=element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"),       
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue",colour = NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "null"),  # Edited code
        legend.position = 'none')
plot(p)
```

[image]

I can resize the window to remove whitespace:

[image]

Comment: I thought that removing white space would make ```ggdraw() + draw_plot(nc_plot)``` put the plot in the bottom left on its own. The answer that is currently accepted solves the final goal in an easy way, but does not do so by removing white space. ```ggdraw() + draw_plot(nc_plot, x = 0, y = 0)``` means that the plot should be in the bottom left, correct? If the plot was created without any white space surrounding the plot, wouldn't you expect the result to look like the image you and @lovalery provided?

Comment: I would change the accepted answer if someone proposed a solution that removes white space surrounding the plot so that ```ggdraw() + draw_plot(nc_plot, x = 0, y = 0)``` makes the plot appear in the bottom left. Is this possible?